# Python- sum() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
numlist = [10,20,5,30]
print numlist
print sum(numlist)

TypeError: sum() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I am trying to use sum function over a list. Python-2.7

Built in function syntax- `sum(iteration[,start])` with start default to 0

Alternatively tried the following:

```
print sum(numlist[,0])
```

error: invalid syntax

Comment: You have masked the function `sum` with something else (I'm guessing). Have you defined a function called `sum`? Have you done `from some_library import *`?

Comment: this is the first line of code in my python interpreter. So there is no function sum called before.

Comment: @JyoNookula: what does `print sum` and `print sum.__module__` produce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *redefined* the `sum()` function. You did this somewhere:

```
def sum(arg1, arg2):
    # ...
```

or used an import to add that name to your current namespace.

and that's the function you are now calling, not the built-in.

If you use:

```
import __builtin__

print __builtin__.sum(numlist)
```

it'll work. When working in the interpreter you could just *delete* the other function for the built-in to 'reappear':

```
del sum
print sum(numlist)
```

In a script, find the `def sum(...):` definition and rename it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You or one of your imports redefined the `sum` builtin:

```
>>> def sum(a,b):
    pass

>>> numlist = [10,20,5,30]
>>> print sum(numlist)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    print sum(numlist)
TypeError: sum() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Fix it by calling `del` on sum, or renaming your function in your code:

```
>>> del sum
>>> sum(numlist)
65
```